*-congruent real matrices are real congruent
Description is the same as this. Here is my attempt:
Suppose $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ and $A=CBC^\dagger$ where $C\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ and $\dagger$ refers to transpose conjugation. By taking vectorization, we have
$$
\mathrm{vec}(A)=(\overline{C}\otimes C)\mathrm{vec}(B),
$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. Assume $C=P+iQ$. Then
$$
\mathrm{vec}(A)=(P\otimes P-Q\otimes Q)\mathrm{vec}(B),\quad P\otimes Q=Q\otimes P.
$$
To prove the result, suffice it to find an invertible $R$ such that $R\otimes R=P\otimes P-Q\otimes Q$.

I think it's similar to some Lie algebra problem...... But I cannot solve it.
